# Multiple angular directives referring to the same template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns

I've found myself in a situation where I have 2 isolate scope directives (each managing differentiated scope and dom state) that are referring to a single template.

```
.directive1...
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'template1',

.directive2...
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'template1',
```

I'm used to having a 1-to-1 relationship between my directives and their templates, and this model (2 directives - to - 1 template) has me veering from that pattern.

Is there a good reason I shouldn't have multiple isolate scope directives referring to the same template?

Is this in violation of some 'best practices' design pattern thought?

Are there other design considerations I should be taking into account here?

Answer (score 0):

If directive1 and directive2 are very similar in form and function, I don't see any issue in reusing the same template. Although, if they are so similar it may mean that they should be one directive with parameters/options passed on the scope?

I would add that it would need to be very clear in the naming of all directives/templates involved in the 2-to-1 situation that they are similar, ex: 'apple' directive and 'orange' directive both use the 'fruit' template, similar to a class inheritance pattern.